# Get position of character in collating sequence

Tags: hex, cobol, data-conversion

I'm looking a way to convert ASCII text into hex data, I mean the way of hex that you can obtain making

```
MOVE X'nn'  TO MYVAR.
```

Then I need to use it like a number (COMP-3 I guess).

I tried to move a PIC(X) to a PIC S9(2)V COMP-3 but does not work as I thought...

Further explanation, as my question was marked as unclear:

First of all, sorry, I made this question late in the night and now that I'm reading again, yes, it's unclear.

Now, the real issue is that I want to use a char (let's say "A") as it's hexadecimal numeric representation to use it as a index for a internal table.

For example, in C it could be easy, making:

```
int mynum;
char mytext;

mynum = atoi(mytext);
```

then using `mychar` to access an array. So, in COBOL I have:

```
01 MY-TABLE.
    05 MY-TABLE-ITEM  PIC X OCCURS 1000.

01 MY-TEXT  PIC X 100.
01 MY-TEXT-X PIC X OCCURS 100.
```

Then, I want to iterate `MY-TEXT-X` and transform it into it's hex code to store it into a numeric variable (PIC 9(n)) to use it to access `MY-TABLE-ITEM`, something like:

```
PERFORM VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I > 100
    PERFORM TRANSFORM-DATA

    DISPLAY MY-TABLE-ITEM(MY-NUMBER)
END-PERFORM
```

As I said, I thought I can move a `PIC X` to a `PIC S9(2)V COMP-3` so the numeric variable can get the value but it's not working as I expected...

EDIT:

So I just found my compiler doesn't support intrinsic functions, so that does not help me...

EDIT - Added source code

So, here's the source I'm using, and also displays from complier and executions.

SOURCE:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.  likeatoi.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01  the-char                            PIC X 
                                          VALUE "K".
    01  the-result                          PIC 999.
    01  the-other-result             PACKED-DECIMAL PIC 9(8) 
                                          VALUE ZERO.
    01  FILLER 
    REDEFINES the-other-result. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X.
       05  char-to-convert                 PIC X.
    01 num pic 9(8).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAINLINE.
  *    with instrinsic function
  *    MOVE FUNCTION ORD ( the-char ) 
  *                              TO the-result.
       DISPLAY 
           ">"
           the-char
           "<"
           ">"
           the-result
           "<".

  *    Old School
       MOVE  the-char               TO char-to-convert.
       DISPLAY 
           ">"
           the-char
           "<"
           ">"
           the-other-result
           "<".

       MOVE the-other-result       TO num.
       DISPLAY num.

       STOP RUN.
```

Now, here a detail of all I tried:

1. First, try to compile it wit INTRINSIC FUNCTION ORD:

   `*****   1) 0384: E User-defined word expected instead of reserved word. (scan su`
2. With this compilation, run program (Ignore error):

`COBOL procedure error 211 at line 17 in ./ESCRITORIO/HEX/LIKEATOI.COB
(/home/dohitb/Escritorio/HEX/likeatoi.COB) compiled 17/03/05 20:37:29.`

3. Comment FUNCTION part, then compile again:

`Errors: 0, Warnings: 1, Lines: 37 for program LIKEATOI.`

(Warning for displaying a COMP variable, it's OK)

4. Execute again (without the "num", and still with comp variable):

   `>A<>   <`

   `>A<>A<`
5. Add "num" variable, change char to "K" and change COMP to PACKED-DECIMAL (in HEX: 4B)

   `>K<>   <`

   `>K<>K<`

   `04900000`

So, as I was telling, neither options are working. The most accurate rigth now is using PACKED-DECIMAL with redefines to PIC 9, but with HEX positions higher than "A" it gives a "9" so it's still not valid.

I think it could be a matter of local COLLATION.

FINAL EDIT

Now I made a variant of the original source code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.  likeatoi.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01  the-char                                    PIC X 
                                          VALUE "K".
    01  the-result                                  PIC 999.
    01  the-other-result             BINARY         PIC 9(4) 
                                          VALUE ZERO.
    01  FILLER-1
    REDEFINES the-other-result. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X.
       05  char-to-convert                 PIC X.

    01  the-comp-result              COMP           PIC 9(4)
                                          VALUE ZERO.
    01  FILLER-2
    REDEFINES the-comp-result. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X.
       05  char-to-convert                 PIC X.

    01  the-packed-result            PACKED-DECIMAL PIC 9(4)
                                          VALUE ZERO.
    01  FILLER-3
    REDEFINES the-packed-result. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X.
       05  char-to-convert                 PIC X.

    01 num                                 PIC 9(8).
    01 alfa                                PIC X(20)
       VALUE 'ABCDEFGHIJabcdefghij'.
    01 FILLER REDEFINES alfa.
        05 char                            PIC X OCCURS 20.
    01 w-index                             PIC 99 VALUE ZEROES.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAINLINE.

       PERFORM VARYING w-index FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL w-index > 20
           MOVE char(w-index)       TO the-char

  *        Variations of "Old School" code
           MOVE the-char            TO char-to-convert OF FILLER-1
           MOVE the-char            TO char-to-convert OF FILLER-2
           MOVE the-char            TO char-to-convert OF FILLER-3

           DISPLAY 
           ">"
           the-char
           "<"
           " with BINARY >"
           the-other-result
           "<"

           MOVE the-other-result       TO num
           DISPLAY "Numeric value: " num

           DISPLAY 
           ">"
           the-char
           "<"
           " with COMP >"
           the-comp-result
           "<"

           MOVE the-comp-result       TO num
           DISPLAY "Numeric value: " num

           DISPLAY 
           ">"
           the-char
           "<"
           " with PACKED >"
           the-packed-result
           "<"

           MOVE the-packed-result       TO num
           DISPLAY "Numeric value: " num
       END-PERFORM.

       STOP RUN.
```

And, for my surprise, it's giving me this output

```
>A< with BINARY >A<

Numeric value: 00000065

>A< with COMP >A<

Numeric value: 00000100
```

(and so on...) So now looks like it's working... Could it be because the first try I made I was working with 05-LEVEL variables?

Looks like now it's done!

Thanks for all, Bill, you will figure on the greetings section of my project :)

At last, one detail.

If I make a "MOVE"

```
MOVE 'A'     TO CHAR
```

Then do all the binary stuff, the results are different... here an example.

with `VALUE`, for "D" I get 68, but with `MOVE` I get 60...

Comment: You are going to need to be much clearer. HEX is just a notation, and commonly it is used to describe the bit-patterns of ASCII characters. So... can you provide some examples of what you actually want?

Comment: Tags you add to your question should be relevant. Each tag has a description. If the description does not match something useful which brings searchers to your question, it will just bring people complaining about the use of the tag. They are not "hashtags".

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for your COBOL. In the Intrinsic Functions you may find what you need. But that's a guess.

Comment: I'll suggest you look at the intrinsic functions again (a guess the first time). Since you've not got it yett, look at FUNCTION ORD.

Comment: Looks like ORD will work. Sorry I didn't put enough attention to the intrinsic functions.

Comment: @BillWoodger just found my compiler doesn't work with functions. I'm using a virtual machine that comes with a COBOL course, but I think it's RM/COBOL compiler what I'm using...

Comment: Are you sure? You have shown an in-line PERFORM, which is available in the 1985 COBOL Standard, and intrinsic functions were a 1989 Addendum to that Standard. It's unlikely you have a 1985-Standard compiler which does not have intrinsic functions. Check against some examples. If it turns out to be the case, how about GnuCOBOL, on SourceForge.Net. Costs you nothing, doesn't need a virtual machine and has the standard intrinsic functions.

Comment: 01 somename. 05  FILLER PIC X VALUE LOW-VALUES. 05  the-character PIC X. 01 character-index REDEFINES somename BINARY PIC 9(4). MOVE yourchar to the-character. Use character-index as your value. It's the "old" way (variations possible) of doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't worked... I tried the move 'B' to char, then move to binary, and when displaying I only see the same character. When I'm trying to access my table it gives me a out-of-index (kinda) error. If I move the binary pic to a PIC 9(4) and display it, I give "6298" (1B10) as a result... with "C" on the PIC X I get "1C10" as a result... :(

Comment: OK, both suggestions work for me with GnuCOBOL.

Comment: So, you have an RM/COBOL (Ryan McFarland, now owned by Micro Focus) which is 1985 compliant, but does not include the intrinsic functions. One mystery solved. Take my data-definitions, exactly as they are. If it doesn't compile with BINARY, make it COMP. Don't change the length of anything. Compile and try again. You can delete everything to do with the intrinsic function if you like.

Comment: I did it on step 4. You can see the output...

Comment: Can you replace the whole version of my program in your question with the one which has a four-digit binary value, not an 8-digit packed-decimal? If it still produces A for A input, MOVE the binary to a PIC ZZZ9 field and DISPLAY that field as well.

Comment: Done, with final conclussion (adding 8 when data is not directly assigned)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @BillWoodger damn! thought I answered this before... so I wrote some fun code using the things I learned here, you may like to see it? https://github.com/DoHITB/SHA1.cob/blob/master/SHA1HEX.CBL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been suffering from using an old compiler. It is to the COBOL 85 Standard, but does not have the intrinsic functions which were a 1989 Extension to the Standard.

Also, it has a non-Standard behaviour which I have not encountered before, which is difficult to explain fully (not having access to that compiler).

The point of using the > and < in the DISPLAY is so that you always know exactly how long each output field is. You know whether there is a blank, or some non-printable character. Your DISPLAY of fields defined as COMP and BINARY only show one character, rather than four numeric digits which would typically be held in two bytes of storage (like an INT, except with a limit of 9999).

Therefore I suggested the MOVE, where you then get the expected result when defined as BINARY and an... unexplained result when defined as COMP.

One explanation for the COMP result may be that COMPUTATIONAL fields are entirely down to the compiler implementor to define. So what is COMP on one system may not be the same type of field as COMP on another system (same with COMP-1, COMP-2, COMP-3 etC). This is why the 1985 Standard introduced new names (for example BINARY and PACKED-DECIMAL) so that they would be portable across COBOL compilers.

If you are stuck with using that compiler, you are unfortunate. If you have the possibility of using another compiler, you can find, amongst other choices, the open-source GnuCOBOL (I am a moderator on the discussion area of the GnuCOBOL project at SourceForge.Net). Use a different compiler if you can.

Here's an example program which will work on modern COBOL compilers using both the intrinsic function ORD and a way it used to be done (and probably is still done). Note, if your COMP field is "little endian", swap the order of the FILLER and field under the REDEFINES.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.  likeatoi.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  the-char                            PIC X 
                                              VALUE "A".
   01  the-result                          PIC 999.
   01  the-other-result             BINARY PIC 9(4) 
                                              VALUE ZERO.
   01  FILLER 
        REDEFINES the-other-result. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X.
       05  char-to-convert                 PIC X.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
  *    with instrinsic function
       MOVE FUNCTION ORD ( the-char ) 
                                    TO the-result
       DISPLAY 
               ">"
               the-char
               "<"
               ">"
               the-result
               "<"

  *    Old School
       MOVE  the-char               TO char-to-convert
       DISPLAY 
               ">"
               the-char
               "<"
               ">"
               the-other-result
               "<"

       STOP RUN
       .
```

The ORD is easy, it is effectively the same as your atoi in C (assuming that that gives you the position in the collating sequenece).

In the second, since COBOL, traditionally, can't have a one-byte binary, is a way, using REDEFINES, to get a character in the low-order part of a two-byte binary, so that the whole binary field represents the "numeric value" of the representation of that character.

The output from the above is:

```
>A<>066<
>A<>0065<
```

Note that ORD gives the *position* in the collating sequence (binary zero with ORD would return one) and the second is just giving the direct representation (binary zero would give zero).

To use either value you may want to "re-base" afterwards if you are only interested in printable characters.

Note, I'm confused that you have a compiler which supports in-line PERFORM but not intrinsic functions. If a USAGE of BINARY is rejected, use COMP instead.

Comment: Tried but, as I told you, it failed. Tried combinations... COMP, COMP-3, BINARY... the most accurate is PACKED-DECIMAL working with a PIC 9(2) PACKED-DECIMAL and then with a REDEFINES PIC S9(3). With this configuration, for "A" it gives me "412", for "B" gives me "422" and so on. I saw that the two first digits are the correct hex value so it's ok to me, but when I was waiting a kind of "4A" i'm getting "49" (that's, for all number gretaer or equal than "A", it appears a "9"...

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to your question, please?